# How to send and receive from the serial port for the device side?

Tags: python, c, uart

I try to make communication between serial port and my device;  sending and receiving data:

```
 /*************Receiving Data***************/
           p_rx_buffer = &rx_buffer[0];
    int rx_length = dev_uart_ptr->uart_read(&rx_buffer, 255);
    //int rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);        //Filestream, buffer to store in, number of bytes to read (max)
    //Bytes received
    if (rx_length < 0)
            {
                xprintf("Error");
            }
            else if (rx_length == 0)
            {
                xprintf("No data");
            }
            else
            {
                //Bytes received
                rx_buffer[rx_length] = '\0';
                xprintf("%i bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx_buffer);
            }

       /*************End Receiving Data ***********/

        /*************Sending Data******************/
         p_tx_buffer = &tx_buffer[0];
        *p_tx_buffer++ = 'H';
        *p_tx_buffer++ = 'e';
        *p_tx_buffer++ = 'l';
        *p_tx_buffer++ = 'l';
        *p_tx_buffer++ = 'o';
         dev_uart_ptr->uart_write(&tx_buffer[0], 255);
```

This is my file in python:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
port='COM4',\
baudrate=230400,\
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
timeout=0)

print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used

ser.write('hello')     # write a string
str=ser.readline()
while True:
  print(ser.read(30).decode('latin9').encode('utf8'))
ser.close()             # close ports
```

That is the result that I have, Firstly, I have a coding problem:

```
 e2 
                ┬ä  
  ├ö    ┬á  ├Ç  ├┤  (
  t      d>  d>  d>  d>  d>
 d>  d>  d>  d>  d>  d>  d>  d
>  d>  d>  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê?
  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê
?  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê?  ├ê? test
_Trig
AES2 irq test
Hello
```

Secondly, The receiving data doesn't work at all, it shows me the msg "Error".

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: Step 1 with serial communication is to check your port settings.  A baud rate of 230400 looks insane to me - we can't see your `c` code configuration but I wonder whether it matches.  In any case, 230400 baud is ridiculously fast.  If you don't have amazing cables this has a high probability of failure, especially with no parity checks.  Slow down to 9600 baud to test and then ramp up speed once everything is working.  Bad cables, long runs, and ambient electrical noise will limit your achievable baud rate.  Be conservative when developing.

Comment: I change the baud rate to 9600 but I still have the same problem of encoding.

Comment: The cable is one of the lesser problems with that bitrate. Not sure what you mean with "amazing cables", but a normal data cable will do well if the rest of the system supports this rate. Problem is the length which should be not more than 1-2m to be on the safe side.

Comment: I think that the problem is just with this line: print(ser.read(30).decode('latin9').encode('utf8'))  I think that I must change the way the coding but i don't know whoch one to choose.

Comment: Well, your code is far from complete so it's difficult to say what the problem is.  I see `Hello` in your Tx data and I see `Hello` in your Rx output so it isn't clear what you're talking about here... what is `tx_buffer`?  How big is it?  You're sending 255 bytes so...   What we really need is a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf If this is RS-232 then cables very much make a difference.  I've seen systems that support high bitrates but that fail with baud rates as low as 19.2kbps with mediocre cables (only moderate shielding, etc), even with cable lengths shorter than 3m.  This was in an industrial environment, mind you, where there was a lot of EMF noise from equipment, but it certainly *can* be the case that high bitrate can cause data corruption.  As a rule, I always suggest to test RS-232 at lower speeds to rule out a hardware, EMF, or cabling issue.

Comment: @J...: I did not talk about using unshielded cables, but from your post, it look as if you think there must be some super expensive high-shielded, impedance matched etc. cable be used. Actually the serial drivers make much more of a difference. Starting from drive current, tx/rx voltage margin, noise-immunity, etc. I already wrote it should be around 2m max, for longer distances, of course you have to use better equipment the longer the lines. I think wen can safely assume a non-industrial environment. Nevertheless, this is not a programming issue, and not to be discussed here.

Comment: @Olaf I mean "amazing" as "uncommonly well constructed", doubly so given that a lot of RS-232 cables are user constructed with whatever cable is on hand - that doesn't have to mean expensive.  Industrial environment was just an example - there can be noise sources everywhere, especially with external devices (which can form ground loops, etc).  It's a reasonable first step when debugging a serial problem to slow down the bitrate - failing to understand and eliminate this as a potential source of problem is a serious failure on the part of the developer so, yes, it certainly does belong here.

Comment: @J... "uncommonly well constructed" - I have no idea what quality standards you are used to, but to me a normal quality cable will do well.

Comment: @Olaf Because you have not experienced it does not mean that it does not exist.  I don't know what to say other than that I *have* very certainly experienced systems that were subject to transmission failures at high baud rates with some (perfectly intact and undamaged) cables and not others.  Sensible protocols will tolerate and correct such errors, so maybe you wouldn't notice in most cases, but for raw RS-232 with no parity checks it can really be a problem.

Comment: The problem was my buffer's size which it must be equals to 5.  the problem is solved. Thank you.